# How to create a google ads in static HTML website?

Tags: adsense

How to create a google ads in static HTML website?

I have a standard htm file how can I add the google adds and how to create add in google?

Answer (score 3):

The same way as you'd add AdSense units to any other page. See Google's AdSense documentation at:

http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=179887